# Map function error in Python

Tags: python

I tried to run the following code.

```
def fahrenheit(T):
    return (9.0/5)*T + 32

temp = [2 , 43 , 54 , 67 , 78 , 89.9]

map(fahrenheit,temp)
```

Why does map function prints

```
<map at 0x15a6cf17550>
```

Comment: Not everything you do not understand is an error. `map` returns a map object. You can convert it to a list by calling `list()`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `list(map(fahrenheit,temp))` since you need list representation

```
[35.6, 109.4, 129.2, 152.60000000000002, 172.4, 193.82000000000002]
```